# Can I place multiple optional constraints on a generic type where only one needs to be enforced?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I would like to put constraints on the generic types below, though I'm not sure if it is possible to do it the way I'm intending.

```
public interface IMyClass<in TA, in TB>
{
    bool MyMethod<TX, TY>(TX argumentX, TY argumentY);
}

public class MyClass<TA, TB> : IMyClass<TA, TB>
{
    public bool MyMethod<TX, TY>(TX argumentX, IEnumerable<TY> argumentsY)
    {
        // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

The types TX and TY are meant to represent TA and TB, but need to be interchangeable (which is why I could not use TA and TB in the method without duplicating code).  This is how the constraints would need to function:

- TX must be the same type as either TA or TB.
- TY must be the same type as either TA or TB.
- If TX is the same type as TA, TY must be the same type as TB (and v.v.).

Is there a way to enforce this at design time using generic constraints or must I implement it using exceptions to fail at run time?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, generic constraints are additive and cannot be switched on or off based on boolean logic. It's highly questionable what exactly you'd be able to do *generically* that would fit under those types of constraints as well.

Comment: I feared this. I may need to take a different approach. To answer your not-question, I wanted to call this method two different ways (A,B and B,A) without duplicating code or having to instantiate the object twice with inverted types.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but you could solve the problem with two overloaded methods.

```
public class MyClass<TA, TB> : IMyClass<TA, TB>
{
    public bool MyMethod(TA argumentX, TB argumentY)
    {
        string argX = SpecialPreFormatterForTA(argumentX);
        string argY = SpecialPreFormatterForTB(argumentY);
        return MyMethodCommon(argX, argY);
    }

    public bool MyMethod(TB argumentX, TA argumentY)
    {
        string argX = SpecialPreFormatterForTB(argumentX);
        string argY = SpecialPreFormatterForTA(argumentY);
        return MyMethodCommon(argX, argY);
    }

    private bool MyMethodCommon(string argX, string argY)
    {
        // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

I made some modifications and some assumptions on what you are doing with your code to help demonstrate the point. You can do whatever specific formatting you need to do in each overloaded method then call, then you can have both functions call a 3rd function that does not care what the types of the two original arguments where to reduce code re-use.

Comment: When I was simplifying the code for this question, I made a mistake - the second method argument is actually a collection (see edit). I need to iterate through argumentsY (and need to be able to do it with both type TA and type TB). I could overload the method, but there is no code that can be extracted into a common method (that is already done). I'm kind of stuck between the "Don't repeat yourself" rule and having clean, clear code.

Comment: @yelxe is there a common base or interface that both TA and TB implement? The problem is solvable if there is.

Comment: One of the types will be an ORM Model Object while the other will be a WCF Data Transfer Object. The only element I can count on being common between them is the ObjId. If I set up an abstract class or interface for all Models and DTOs, it would not limit use to the specific Model and DTO I'm specifying during use.

Comment: See, this is why you should provide all the details, this sounds like a job that [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) could be perfect for. It could transform your ORM objects in to your DTO objects for you.